# text data processed by R in a shell script sh

Tags: linux, r, shell

I need to analyze some text files with R and create a (text?) output with maximum,minimum,sum,variance etc.
My problem is that i don't know how to do that!

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo "insert file"
 read MyFile
 ....
```

Does it exist a line code to call R, import my file, maybe make some elaborations and print the output?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you hell bent on using a bash script? R has all the facilities to import a number of files, do the crunching and write the output almost any way you can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rscript command in order to run R code from bash. e.g.

```
Rscript -e "source('yourFile.R')" -e "yourFunction()"
```

Comment: ok, thanks but what's in "yourfile.R"? and "yourFunction()" ? i mean, if i want to compute the median value of myfile.txt what is the right code?